# Как передать переменную во внешнюю функцию?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Такой вопрос, как мне из второго запроса передать V в первый?

Использую модуль mysql2, если интересно, хотя я думаю что это лишняя информация

```
let itemList = [];
let v = 0;
connection.query("SELECT * FROM bags WHERE uid = ? ",[usid],function(err,results,fields){   
    let item = ``;
    let v = 0;
    for(let i = 0;i<=results.length-1;i++) {
        if(!checkItem(results[i].name)){
            itemList.push({name:results[i].name,am:1});
        } else {
            itemList[checkIdItem(results[i].name)].am++;
        }
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name = ?",[results[i].name],function(err,results,fields){
            v = v+results[0].v;
        });
        console.log(v)
   } 
});
```

Comment: Сделать из двух запросов один.

Comment: Как же вы предлагаете это сделать?

Comment: Добавить в таблицу bags поле v?
Тогда придётся регулярно синхронизировать весы предметов

Comment: *как мне из второго запроса передать V в первый?* Начать с того, что отправлять результат в прошлое - не получится. Как Вы представляете передачу в первый запрос результата, который ещё не получен, ибо второй запрос даже и не думал начинаться? *Как же вы предлагаете это сделать?* Я предлагаю озвучить смысл выполняемого действа, и показать структуры участвующих в нём таблиц с пояснением, что где хранится и к чему цепляется. Можно даже примером - вот таблицы, вот в них такие данные, вот такие исходные, вот так должно получиться.

Comment: Пишу бота, который выводил бы инвентарь Юзера с определённым UID

Структура bags (Таблица инвентарей):
uid (var 32) name (var 64).

Структура items ( Таблица итемов ):
name (var 32) v (var 64) (Последнее - вес предмета).

Конкретно проблема с тем, чтобы вывести общий вес, тоесть допустим, две бутылки воды по 1 кг каждая, выводится в embed - 2 - Бутылка воды | 1кг/2кг

Comment: Пожалуйста, все факты - в текст вопроса, а не в комментарии (ссылка "править" под ним). Структуру - в виде CREATE TABLE. И не надо давать половину сведений - давайте полностью.

Comment: `select b.name, sum(i.v) v from bags b, items i where i.name=b.name and uid=? group by b.name` Хотя текущий ваш код считает что то более интересное, он в v суммирует веса вообще всего что найдет в items нарастающим итогом. И разная размерность поля name намекает, что в bags может быть внесено имя, которое по размеру не влезет в items, а значит возможно у вас связь таблиц и не по этому полю